# C# - How to change Fore Color to custom RGB value

Tags: c#, colors, rgb

I created a label and need to change the color of it programmatically to a specific RGB color code, if a certain event triggers.

I tried it like this:

```
statusStripTestLabel.ForeColor = new Color(128, 64, 64);
```

*BONUS:*

```
Set it to a RGBA color.
```

But I get `Color does not have a constructor which accepts 3 arguments.`

So how do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
statusStripTestLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 64, 64); //Alpha is implicitly 255.

statusStripTestLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 64, 64); //Alpha is explicitly 255. You can change the value of the first parameter to specify the alpha you want.
```

Comment: Missed an argument there.

Comment: Indeed, just add another value for A (or Alpha to indicate Opacity) as 255 so that reads as Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 64, 64);

Comment: Actually, I didn't. The method FromArgb() has 4 overloads. If you want to specify the alpha, you can use the overload that accepts 4 arguments. Since the question didn't bother to specify the alpha, he can use the overload that accepts the 3 arguments above (int red, int green, int blue).

Comment: Alpha is implicitly 255 when you use the overload above.

Answer (score 0):

What u are trying is somewhat right in JAVA. 
In c# it is,

yourComponent. ForeColor=Color. FromArgb(theARGB_Code) ;

*Note not all components support transparency